# Perl Regular Expression for Hash values

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have hash values which looks like this:

```
   build -var ver=2.1.0.0 -var buildnum=WorkSet/2.1.0_suiteB_3o -var product=cisco6500 platform=NSA prodtype=Debug HOST=10.9.33.22 -var clist=

   build -var ver=2.1.0.0 -var buildnum=WorkSet/2.1.0_suiteB_3o -var product=juniper6700 platform=NSA prodtype=Prod HOST=10.9.33.22 -var clist=
```

I am trying to seperate out the hash value to create another hash such that it looks as below:

```
   My $list = {'2.1.0.0' => { 'branch' => Workset/2.1.0'
               'products' => [{product => 'cisco6500',
                                prodType => 'Debug'},
                                {product => 'juniper6700',
                                prodType => 'Prod'}]
```

}
}

I have written something like this:

```
    if ($cmd =~ m/ver=(\d.\d.\d.\d)/){
            $version = $1;
    }
    if ($cmd =~ m/buildnum=(\w+.\/\d.\d.\d)/){
            $branch = $1;
    }
    if ($cmd =~ m/product=(\s+)/){
            $product = $1;
    }
```

}

Now, I getting confused how to insert the hash in the hash and array simultaneously. Please if anyone can suggest something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch can be built without a problem:

```
$list->{$version}{branch} = $branch;
```

For products, you should push them onto the array that you have to dereference:

```
push @{ $list->{$version}{products} },
        { product  => $product,
          prodType => $prodtype,
        };
```

In recent versions of Perl, the dereference is not needed, so you can push directly to an array reference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply..Pls can you tell me how to deference the variable stored in the above hashes of arrays..The list->{$version}{branch} can be deferenced as $list->{$version}->{branch}. Thank you.

Comment: @deep: Just use `$list->{$version}{products}[0]{product}` etc.